# How to reset state in react navigation v5?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can I use [navigation.reset](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#reset) prop to reset (or create a new navigation history) current navigation state and create a new one.

I have such router structure (see example below) and I want to navigate from `Screen 3` to the `Screen4`. After navigation, I should be able to press back button to navigate back in history. In my case it should be the default screen (`Screen5`) of `Tab2`.

```
NativeStackNavigator
  Screen1
     BottomTabNavigator
       Tab1
       Tab2
         NativeStackNavigator
            Screen5 (default) <- navigate here after back button was pressed
            Screen4 <- to this route
       Tab3
       Tab4
  Screen2
  Screen3 <- from this route
```

Currently, I was able to achieve this by following code. But, unfortunately the `back` button doesn't exist inside the header.

```js
props.navigation.reset({
  index: 1,
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Screen1',
      params: {
        screen: 'Tab2',
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Screen1',
      params: {
        screen: 'Tab2',
        params: { screen: 'Screen4' },
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

Additional info:

`package.json`

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.5.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.5.0",
"react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
```

**Update #1**
I would rather expect to keep history after resetting a state.

**Update #2**
I was able to accomplish this task by using the following example. Thank to @satya164.

```js
navigation.navigate('Screen1', {
  screen: 'Tab2',
  params: {
    initial: false,
    screen: 'Screen4',
  },
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify child navigator's state in `state` property of `route`:

```js
navigation.reset({
  index: 1,
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'Screen1',
      state: {
        routes: [{ name: 'Tab2' }],
      },
    },
    {
      name: 'Screen1',
      state: {
        routes: [
          {
            name: 'Tab2',
            state: {
              routes: [{ name: 'Screen5' }, { name: 'Screen4' }]
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ],
})
```

But this is going to reset your navigation state with completely new state, unmounting and remounting some screens. You can keep the old routes like shown in [`dispatch` docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-prop/#dispatch) but it only applies to current navigator, not child navigator.

Here, it seems like you just want `navigate`, not `reset`. If `Screen5` is the `initialRouteName` in your native stack, then:

```js
navigation.navigate('Screen1', {
  screen: 'Tab2',
  params: {
    initial: false,
    screen: 'Screen4',
  },
});
```

Comment: The first option is working. P.S. I don't know why but the `navigate` method of `react-native-screens` seems to have a bug. After calling navigate my application opens/closes screens and after remove everything and stops on the default screen. I'll post the issue to the GitHub

Comment: Could please tell me if it possible to keep the router state on other tabs the same as before. Only change the half of the state?